# How to disable Firefox's default drag and drop on all images behavior with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser

Firefox has this annoying behavior that it let's the user drag and drop any image element by default. How can I cleanly disable this default behavior with jQuery?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The following will do it in Firefox 3 and later:

```
$(document).on("dragstart", function() {
     return false;
});
```

If you would prefer not to disable all drags (e.g. you may wish to still allow users to drag links to their link toolbar), you could make sure only `<img>` element drags are prevented:

```
$(document).on("dragstart", function(e) {
     if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "IMG") {
         return false;
     }
});
```

Bear in mind that this will allow images within links to be dragged.

Comment: with this solution all dragstart events will be disabled, including links (e.g. dragging your links to the URL bar)

Comment: With this solution, I can't enable draggable for any elements with jQuery UI. Any possibility to both disable default drag-n-drop and add my own?

Comment: @OlleHärstedt: You could adapt the second example to not return `false` for elements that are draggable via jQuery UI. I don't know the details of how jQuery UI draggables work though, sorry.

Comment: I'm afraid not, since the elements which are draggable or not change. So I need a way to unset "return false" to it's default. But I've opened another SO-question for that, thanks. :)

Answer (score 13):

If Javascript is an optional requirement, you can try with CSS

```
.wrapper img {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: This solution is not very helpful if I want the element to be draggable but I don't want the default browser drag

Answer (score 12):

Does it need to be jQuery? You just need to define a callback function for your mousedown event on the image(s) in question with `event.preventDefault()`.

So your image tag could look like this:

`<img src="myimage.jpg" onmousedown="if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault()" />`

The additional `if` is needed because otherwise IE throws an error. If you want this for all image tags you just need to iterate through the `img`tags with jQuery and attach the onmousedown event handler.

There is a nice explanation (and example) on this page: "[Disable image dragging in FireFox](http://www.redips.net/firefox/disable-image-dragging/)" and a not as well documented version is here using jQuery as reference: "[Disable Firefox Image Drag](http://develobert.blogspot.com/2008/10/disable-firefox-image-drag.html)"

Comment: If you're using an event handler attribute you can just do `onmousedown="return false;"`, which will work in all browsers.

Comment: I am happy with Tim Down's solution, because it is very simple, I mentioned jQuery because I thought it would be a little more complex. Thank you for your answer. Upvote.

Comment: The preventDefault() is a very good hint - did a perfect job for me!

Comment: Careful, doing this bit me recently... preventing default on mousedown will also prevent useful things like capture of mouseup events outside an iframe (see discussion at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1419). Preventing the default action on dragstart as in other answers seems a bit safer to me.

Answer (score 7):

Solution without jQuery:

```
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Referencing **Tim Down**'s solution, you can achieve the equivalent of his second code snippet of only disabling `img` drags while using jQuery:

```
$(document).on("dragstart", "img", function() {
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cover your image with an empty div element:

```
.img-container{
    position: relative;
}
.prevent-drag{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

<div class="img-container">
    <div class="prevent-drag"></div>
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember my source but work

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // register onLoad event with anonymous function
window.onload = function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,// define event (cross browser)
        imgs,                   // images collection
        i;                      // used in local loop
    // if preventDefault exists, then define onmousedown event handlers
    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        // collect all images on the page
        imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        // loop through fetched images
        for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            // and define onmousedown event handler
            imgs[i].onmousedown = disableDragging;
        }
    }
};

// disable image dragging
function disableDragging(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```