# JQuery Jquery-UI Drag Drop Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my first introduction to JQuery.

This page is under development [here](http://www.guygar.com/eXistenZ/index.html).

The issue: although the first element of the menu on the right side performs the drag and drop well:

dragging it to the content area runs with success.

As an side-effect all the images/icons on the page somehow became draggable also!

The working of correct icons behaves the correct way; but the other icons can be dragged to any page of the page.

Why is this happening please and how do I avoid it?

```
$( init );

function init()
{
    $('#artOfBeing').draggable( {containment: '#dataFrame', cursor: 'pointer', snap: '#dataFrame'});
    $('#sadWorld').draggable( {containment: '#dataFrame', cursor: 'pointer', snap: '#dataFrame'});

    $('#dataFrame').droppable( {     drop: handleDropEvent   } );   
}
```

Thank you for your insigtes and excuse the newbie question.

Best regards.

```
function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {   var draggable = ui.draggable;   alert( 'The square with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' ); }
```

Just tried Safari and Google Chrome and they are behaving with this issue as well.

EDIT: [How to disable Firefox's default drag and drop on all images behavior with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873595/how-to-disable-firefoxs-default-drag-and-drop-on-all-images-behavior-with-jquer) deals with this issue. it is the default behaviour of the browsers!

Comment: I don't see the problem. I can drag the top and bottom icons from the right into the big panel in the middle. I can't drag anything else.

Comment: Yes I just checked in IE9 I cannot move anything else but he Firefox I can.

Comment: I don't understand, it looks like it's working as intended. Everything you defined in the init is draggable and drop fine. I checked in Firefox - no issues.

Comment: you mean if you select an icon and drag it with mouse down in Firefox the icon does not move? what i get is the image/icon can be moved but letting the mouse go cancels the movement and behaves like so in Safari and Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error could be the function "handleDropEvent" because the function is not defined.

Fix bug and retry

Comment: function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {   var draggable = ui.draggable;   alert( 'The square with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' ); } added this but the issue did not change in Firefox.